# Merge lines that share the same key into one line

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe and would like to make another column that combines the columns whose name begins with the same `value` in `Answer` and `QID`.

That is to say, having the following Dataframe

```
    QID     Category    Text    QType   Question:   Answer0     Answer1     Country
0   16  Automotive  Access to car   Single  Do you have access to a car?    I own a car/cars    I own a car/cars  UK
1   16  Automotive  Access to car   Single  Do you have access to a car?    I lease/ have a company car     I lease/have a company car  UK
2   16  Automotive  Access to car   Single  Do you have access to a car?    I have access to a car/cars     I have access to a car/cars     UK
3   16  Automotive  Access to car   Single  Do you have access to a car?    No, I don’t have access to a car/cars   No, I don't have access to a car    UK
4   16  Automotive  Access to car   Single  Do you have access to a car?    Prefer not to say   Prefer not to say   UK
```

I would like to get the following as a result:

```
        QID     Category    Text    QType   Question:   Answer0     Answer1     Answer2    Answer3  Country    Answers
    0   16  Automotive  Access to car   Single  Do you have access to a car?    I own a car/cars    I lease/ have a company car      I have access to a car/cars    No, I don’t have access to a car/cars    UK    ['I own a car/cars', 'I lease/ have a company car'   ,'I have access to a car/cars', 'No, I don’t have access to a car/cars', 'Prefer not to say     Prefer not to say']
```

So far I have tried the following:

```
previous_qid = None
i = 0
j = 0
answers = []
new_row = {}
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    # get QID
    qid = row['QID']
    if qid == previous_qid:
        i+=1
        new_row['Answer'+str(i)]=row['Answer0']
        answers.append(row['Answer0'])
    elif new_row != {}:
        # we moved to a new row
        new_row['QID'] = qid
        new_row['Question'] = row['Question']
        new_row['Answers'] = answers
        # we create a new row in the new_dataframe
        new_df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
        # we clean up everything to receive the next row
        answers = []
        i=0
        j+=1
        new_row = {}
        # we add the information of the current row
        new_row['Answer'+str(i)]=row['Answer0']
        answers.append(row['Answer0'])
    previous_qid = qid
```

But `new_df` results empty.

Comment: post more basic example, and expected result. Above expected result makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is logically grouping by *QID* getting a list of *Answers* then splitting list back into columns

```py
import re
data = """    QID     Category    Text    QType   Question:   Answer0     Answer1     Country
0   16  Automotive  Access to car   Single  Do you have access to a car?    I own a car/cars    I own a car/cars  UK
1   16  Automotive  Access to car   Single  Do you have access to a car?    I lease/ have a company car     I lease/have a company car  UK
2   16  Automotive  Access to car   Single  Do you have access to a car?    I have access to a car/cars     I have access to a car/cars     UK
3   16  Automotive  Access to car   Single  Do you have access to a car?    No, I don’t have access to a car/cars   No, I don't have access to a car    UK
4   16  Automotive  Access to car   Single  Do you have access to a car?    Prefer not to say   Prefer not to say   UK"""
a = [[t.strip() for t in re.split("  ",l) if t!=""]  for l in [re.sub("([0-9]?[ ])*(.*)", r"\2", l) for l in data.split("\n")]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=a[1:], columns=a[0])

# lazy - want first of all attributes except QID and Answer columns
agg = {col:"first" for col in list(df.columns) if col!="QID" and "Answer" not in col}
# get a list of all answers in Answer0 for a QID
agg = {**agg, **{"Answer0":lambda s: list(s)}}

# helper function for row call.  not needed but makes more readable
def ans(r, i):
    return "" if i>=len(r["AnswerT"]) else r["AnswerT"][i]

# split list from aggregation back out into columns using assign
# rename Answer0 to AnserT from aggregation so that it can be referred to.  
# AnswerT drop it when don't want it any more
dfgrouped = df.groupby("QID").agg(agg).reset_index().rename(columns={"Answer0":"AnswerT"}).assign(
    Answer0=lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda r: ans(r, 0), axis=1),
    Answer1=lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda r: ans(r, 1), axis=1),
    Answer2=lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda r: ans(r, 2), axis=1),
    Answer3=lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda r: ans(r, 3), axis=1),
    Answer4=lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda r: ans(r, 4), axis=1),
    Answer5=lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda r: ans(r, 5), axis=1),
    Answer6=lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda r: ans(r, 6), axis=1),
).drop("AnswerT", axis=1)

print(dfgrouped.to_string(index=False))
```

**output**

```
QID    Category           Text   QType                     Question: Country           Answer0                      Answer1                      Answer2                                Answer3            Answer4 Answer5 Answer6
 16  Automotive  Access to car  Single  Do you have access to a car?      UK  I own a car/cars  I lease/ have a company car  I have access to a car/cars  No, I don’t have access to a car/cars  Prefer not to say
```

#### more dynamic

This gets a bit more into advanced `python`.  Use of `**kwargs` and `functools.partial`.  In reality it's still static,  columns is defined as a constant `MAXANS`

```py
import functools 
MAXANS=8
def ansassign(dfa, row=0):
    return dfa.apply(lambda r: "" if row>=len(r["AnswerT"]) else r["AnswerT"][row], axis=1)
dfgrouped = df.groupby("QID").agg(agg).reset_index().rename(columns={"Answer0":"AnswerT"}).assign(
    **{f"Answer{i}":functools.partial(ansassign, row=i) for i in range(MAXANS)}
).drop("AnswerT", axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Actually I might have more Answers than only 7, How could I make it dynamic to get as many answers as there are row with the same (`QID`,`Question:`)?

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica I can't think of a way to do truly dynamically as row by row number of items in list cannot be found.  Have updated,  but beware few people are expert in this type of coding.

Comment: Your update is really cool! So advanced! I was thinking about sharing the [xlsx of the data I was using for this question](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RZTL9iEVW2uqepZVNPkJ5vt-IXzv66md/view?usp=sharing). Maybe it could help to get the numbers dynamically

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica in many ways I prefer the first approach - it's far more transparent.  80% of time goes on maintaining code... code that uses a lot of advanced concepts is very expensive to maintain.

Comment: Yes, actually I think you are right. I'm working on making your code dynamic with the dataframe I shared. Don't have a clue yet, but I'm sure I can do something. I posted [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63263807/dynamically-merge-lines-that-share-the-same-key-into-one), rather than bothering you here with this dynamic problem and if you want a few more points ^^